# How to show webpshere liberty version in web page

Tags: jsp, websphere-liberty

In a web app i am working on, i am creating an 'About the app' page.
 In this page, i want to show the server info : Websphere Liberty and Java version.

I am working mainly with JSPs, and can not find a way to show this info.

Can it be done? Thanks

SJRM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the server information from the [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). In the servlet you can create JavaBean and populate it with the information about the server:

```
public class EnvironmentInfoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

        EnvironmentInfo environmentInfo = new EnvironmentInfo();
        environmentInfo.setServerInfo(context.getServerInfo());

        req.setAttribute("environmentInfo", environmentInfo);
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("environmentInfo.jsp");
        rd.forward(req, res);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, res);
    }
}
```

JavaBean:

```
public class EnvironmentInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String serverInfo;

    public EnvironmentInfo() {
    }

    public String getServerInfo() {
        return serverInfo;
    }

    public void setServerInfo(String serverInfo) {
        this.serverInfo = serverInfo;
    }
}
```

Then get information in your JSP from the JavaBean by using the expression language:

```
<jsp:useBean id="environmentInfo" class="com.beans.EnvironmentInfo" scope="request"/>
...
<b>${environmentInfo.serverInfo}</b>
...
```

The current version of the Java runtime and a lot of other information you can get by calling [`java.lang.System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) method.